# What does anal.hasnext actually do?

Tags: radare2

I am trying to understand `anal.hasnext` control flow configuration option of Radare. The documentation says "Continue analysis after each function. Forces to find a function, after the end of a function." So how far does it continue analysis after the end of a function. Does it stop after finding one more function after the end or continue further. At what point does it stop? Without this would it stop at the `ret` instruction? Can someone give me code example in `C` where this could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hasnext tries to get the function behind the current one. It also skips padding stuff like int3 (0xcc), nop (0x90) and such (on x86). anal.depth defines the limit of this behaviour. every 'next' function will decrement it by one. For more information see canal.c (__core_anal_fcn) and search for has_next.